# Add 1 to class name on clone (jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, clone

I'm created simple script, this is my jquery:

```
// 
$('.sections a').click(function (e) {
    var clone = $('.sections a ~ div:last').clone();

    $('.sections a').after(clone);
});
```

and html

```
<div class="sections">

    <a href="#add_section">Add section</a>

    <div class="section_1">
        <input type="hidden" name="section_1">
    </div>

</div>
```

and after click link "add section", my script clone last div after anchor.
and with next click i want add one to class and input value for example:

```
    <div class="section_1">
        <input type="hidden" name="section_1">
    </div>

    <div class="section_2">
        <input type="hidden" name="section_2">
    </div>

    <div class="section_3">
        <input type="hidden" name="section_3">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your js:

```
var clones=1;
$('.sections a').click(function (e) {
    var clone = $('.sections a ~ div:last').clone();
    $('.sections a ~ div:last').after(clone);
    clones++;
    clone.attr('class','section_'+clones);
    clone.find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('name','section_'+clones);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/by1os8hx/)

Sorry... I haven't seen the answer of @twain. It's practically the same, I hope the demo helps

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to the document and filtering on the element

```
$(document).on('click', '.sections a', function (e) {
    var clone = $('.sections a ~ div:last').clone();

    //increment attributes here


    $('.sections a').after(clone);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (its a bit dirty, but it should work):

```
$('.sections a').click(function (e) {
    var clone = $('.sections a ~ div:last').clone();
    var currentClass = $('.sections a ~ div:last').attr("class");
    var currentId = currentClass.substr(currentClass.length -1);
    currentId++;

    $(clone).attr("class", "section_" + currentId);
    $(clone).find("input").attr("name", "section_" + currentId);
    $('.sections a ~ div:last').after(clone);
});
```